# Maven set dependency group to a specific version

Tags: maven

Is there any Maven plugin to set a specific a dependencies with a specific groupId to a specific version.
So for example if my project had dependencies like so:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.project.abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>some-artifact-one</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.project.abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>some-artifact-two</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I want a Maven plugin like this to set above dependencies to version 1.0

```
mvn magicplugin:set -Dversion=1.0 -DgroupId=com.mycompany.project.abc
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [versions-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) which is exactly created for such purposes.

Comment: I've tried versions:set but it doesn't support what I need. It only seems to allow you set the project version and not dependencies. And the other goals for dependencies don' t seem to allow you specify a version

Comment: It might help if you define a property in such cases and define them in dependencyManagement so you have single point of change.